# Determine text width

Tags: margins, lengths

For sizing figures in LaTeX it's helpful to know how wide the text is so that figures can be sized to match without rescaling.  LaTeX provides `\textwidth` for reference by other commands, e.g.
    `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}`
but including `\textwidth` "raw" in the document produces errors.

Is there a way to determine what this value is?

Comment: See also [Force stringification of a length](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19633/force-stringification-of-a-length).

Comment: Pretty sweet answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337/13552. You can then write `\convertto{cm}{\the\textwidth}`, for example. The article class should yield `12.12537 cm`.

Comment: @macmadness86: for A4 or letter?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

From http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2712

Using `\the\textwidth` will allow you to see the value LaTeX is using.  However, the default unit of measurement is probably points, not a likely option for your graphics software.

Fortunately, the conversion function is available in the standard `layouts` package:
    `\usepackage{layouts}`
    `...`
    `textwidth in cm: \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textwidth}`
will print the value in cm.  All the usual LaTeX units of measurement are also available if cm aren't what you want.

Comment: `textwidth in inches: \printinunitsof{in}\prntlen{\textwidth}`

Comment: For the article class, this gives the result 4.7747 inches.

Comment: The width in points from `\the\textwidth` is easily converted to cm eg. with a google search like "506.295pt in cm"

Answer (score 16):

The [printlen](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/printlen.html) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\begin{document}
\printlength\textwidth
\end{document}
```

produces "345.0pt". It can print in units other than pt, too.

Comment: `printlen` isn't included by default in teTeX which makes this solution a bit harder, but I'm impressed by the quick response!

Comment: Just use \the, it's built into TeX itself.

Comment: teTeX is unsupported for a couple of years now. You should be using TeXLive instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about teTeX.  Once TeXLive makes it into fink's repository I'll gladly move to it.

Comment: report class appears to be 390pt in case anyone needs to know in the future

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `pgf`

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\the\textwidth \\
\pgfmathparse{\textwidth}
\pgfmathresult pt \\
\end{document}
```

where `\pgfmathparse` returns `\textwidth` in **points** but **without unit** to `\pgfmathresult`, so you have to manually add unit to it

[image: length]

however you know it is always in points.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same challenge. However, I did not manage to use the abovementioned options. My `LaTeX` distribution did not recognized `\printinunitsof` as a valid statement.

What worked perfectly fine for me was to take a screen shot of the PDF and measure the width of the text and the width of the document in pixels using a programme like Paint. As the total document width in cm is known, you can calculate:

```
textwidth_cm = documentwidth_cm*textwidth_pixels/document_pixels
```

The textwidth is also equal to the documentwidth minus the left and right margins. If you explicitly specify the margins (e.g. with the `geometry` package), the textwidth is also easily calculated.