# Adding width of text to node coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, calculations, unit-of-measure

I am currently trying to position some text in the center of a square drawn in a `tikzpicture`, like so:

[image: example image]

However, I am having a bit of trouble.

Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \newcommand{\boxWidth}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxHeight}{3cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosX}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosY}{-5cm};

    \newcommand{\someText}{Hello World};
    \newcommand{\textPosX}{\boxPosX + (\printinunitsof{cm}\widthof{\someText}/2)};
    \newcommand{\textPosY}{\boxPosY + \boxHeight / 2};

    \draw [line width=0.05cm, rounded corners=.3cm, color=red] (\boxPosX,\boxPosY) rectangle ++(\boxWidth, \boxHeight);

    \node at (\textPosX, \textPosY) {\someText};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem arrises when I try using the width of the text: `\widthof{\someText}/2` (from the `calc` package). ([Reference Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length))

According to the same [reference post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length), `\widthof` returns a length in **points**, which is incompatible with **centimeters**. Therefore, I tried converting to centimeters by using the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39383/determine-text-width): `\printinunitsof{cm}\widthof{\someText}`.

However, this still yields an *"Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."*

What am I doing wrong and how can I correctly convert my units from **points** to **centimeters**?

Comment: can you provide a sketch of your desired result. is behind this `tikzpicture`something which require so complicated  code?

Comment: You cannot do computations with `\newcommand`, use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead, e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\textPosX}{\boxPosX + width("\someText")*1pt/2cm};`. But this is absolutely unnecessary here, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Zarko I added a picture to help convey what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code I sort of sense what you might want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \newcommand{\boxWidth}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxHeight}{3cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosX}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosY}{-5cm};

    \newcommand{\someText}{Hello World};
    \node[draw,line width=0.05cm, rounded corners=.3cm, color=red,
    minimum width=\boxWidth,minimum height=\boxHeight,text=black] at 
    ({\boxPosX},{\boxPosY}) {\someText};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\newcommand` use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to do computations, e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\textPosX}{\boxPosX + width("\someText")*1pt/2cm};`. However, I think that all the complicated computations are unnecessary here. To put a text in the center of a box, it suffices to say `\node[draw]{text}`. And then you can do all sorts of spirifankerln like adding a `minimum width`, `rounded corners` etc.

Comment: Why can I do that addition in my new command for `\textPosY`, but I cannot do more complex computation? Why does `\newcommand` allows some computation?

Comment: And I need something complex like this, because I will have several rectangles of the same size, each of which will have a unique string in them. The node method contours around the text **only** and adding redundant spaces is messy in my opinion.

Comment: @DanHoynoski `\newcommand` by itself does not allow for computations. You're loading the `calc` *package* (which is not to be confused with the Ti*k*Z *library* of the same name), which allows you to do computations, but I guess once you load Ti*k*Z, this is sort of obsolete. And no, you can put pretty much anything inside a node of `tikzpicture`, graphics, equations... (just not tikzpictures, at least you shouldn't). There are tons of libraries which allow you to arrage rectangles of the same size, e.g. `matrix` or `chains`.

Comment: you are absolutely correct! Using a node is so much better. And that is strange, because if you set `\textPosX` to `\boxPosX` in my original code above (to prevent that conversion error) and then it compiles just fine even with `\boxPosY + \boxHeight / 2` being there. Are you say that because I am loading the calc package, it added this ability to `\newcommand`?

Comment: @DanHoynoski No, calc does not do any magic of that kind. It is Ti*k*Z which starts to parse these things and then sees "Oh, here is some `x+y`, let's add them." You can always check such things by saying e.g. `\typeout{\boxPosX}` and the you will see whether this is the string `x+y` or the sum.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I appreciate your help. On last question, is there any reason why you used `width` over `\widthof`?

Comment: @DanHoynoski Yes, `width("xyz")` is Ti*k*Z language. So I do not need to load the `calc` *package*. And if there are complications, you're usually better off if you use the tools of one package, rather than mixing them, in which case it is harder to debug.

Answer (score 5):

If the text is to be placed in the centre of the rectangle, simply place it with a node `midway` down the path.

```
\draw [line width=0.05cm, rounded corners=.3cm, color=red] 
(\boxPosX,\boxPosY) rectangle ++(\boxWidth, \boxHeight)node[midway,text=black]{\someText};
```

[image: rectangle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \newcommand{\boxWidth}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxHeight}{3cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosX}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosY}{-5cm};

    \newcommand{\someText}{Hello World};
   %\newcommand{\textPosX}{\boxPosX + (\printinunitsof{cm}\widthof{\someText}/2)};
   %\newcommand{\textPosY}{\boxPosY + \boxHeight / 2};

\draw [line width=0.05cm, rounded corners=.3cm, color=red] 
(\boxPosX,\boxPosY) rectangle ++(\boxWidth, \boxHeight)node[midway,text=black]{\someText};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I did not think about adding another node like this! If I could accept two answers, I would!

Comment: @DanHoynoski The notion of a `path` with Tikz is a notion that is not immediately obvious. Especially since according to the pages of the manual, it does not have exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way. If you have some already drawn rectangles (not nodes), you can use a `fit` node which encompasses rectangle corners and add a label in its center:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \newcommand{\boxWidth}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxHeight}{3cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosX}{5cm};
    \newcommand{\boxPosY}{-5cm};

    \newcommand{\someText}{Hello World};
%    \newcommand{\textPosX}{\boxPosX + (\printinunitsof{cm}\widthof{\someText}/2)};
%    \newcommand{\textPosY}{\boxPosY + \boxHeight / 2};

    \draw [line width=0.05cm, rounded corners=.3cm, color=red] (\boxPosX,\boxPosY) rectangle ++(\boxWidth, \boxHeight);

    \node[fit={(\boxPosX,\boxPosY) (\boxPosX+\boxWidth,\boxPosY+\boxHeight)},  label=center:\someText] {};

    \draw [line width=0.05cm, rounded corners=.3cm, color=green] (-2,-5) coordinate (1) rectangle ++(5,2) coordinate (2);

    \node[fit={(1) (2)},  label=center:\someText] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]